# RSpec mock or stub super in a model

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, module, mocking, rspec

How do I test this tiny part of the module, with super? (superclass is action_dispatch-3.0.1 testing/integration...) The module is included within spec/requests to intercept *post*:

```
module ApiDoc
  def post(path, parameters = nil, headers = nil)
    super
    document_request("post", path, parameters, headers) if ENV['API_DOC'] == "true"
  end
  ...
end
```

I don't want it to run the ActionDispatch::Integration-whatever, but I don't know `how to mock or stub super` to unit test it.

The module is only used within specs, and will have 100% test coverage, which proves those kinds of metrics as useless. I need to unit test it.

An example, if needed, this is how I use the module ApiDoc

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Products API" do
  include ApiDoc  ############## <---- This is my module
  context "POST product" do
    before do
      @hash = {:product => {:name => "Test Name 1", :description => "Some data for testing"}}
    end

    it "can be done with JSON" do
      valid_json = @hash.to_json
      ############### the following 'post' is overriden by ApiDoc
      post("/products.json",valid_json,
       {"CONTENT_TYPE" => "application/json",
        "HTTP_AUTHORIZATION" => ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Basic.encode_credentials("user", "secret")})
      response.should be_success
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check if the method is called on the 'super' class

```
ActionDispatch::Integration.any_instance.should_receive(:post)
```

Since ApiDock is only required for your tests you could also overwrite the post method with alias_method_chain:

```
ActionDispatch::Integration.instance_eval do
  def post_with_apidoc(path, parameters = nil, headers = nil)
    post_without_apidoc
    if ENV['API_DOC'] == "true"
      document_request("post", path, parameters, headers)
    end
  end
  alias_method_chain :post, :apidoc
end
```

Comment: thanks! I'm using mocha, so this works: `ActionDispatch::Integration::Session.any_instance.expects(:post).with xx`, but then I can't mock the ApiDoc.post or -.document_request, as it says it's class (of ApiDoc) is `RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1` How do I mock out those methods in this case? Or do I create a dummy class to include it in, to test that behavior?

Comment: Creating a Dummy class is the better option I think.

Comment: Accepted answer because of the first code line. Unit testing in a dummy class is a good idea. FYI, using `super` is preferred over alias method chaining. They removed a lot of such aliases when refactoring rails 2.x to 3.

Comment: This syntax is for the old RSpec. One thing to note for people wishing to test similar functionality is that perhaps you shouldn't be inheriting at all.  In my case, composition made much more sense and was much easier to test as well. (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)

Answer (score 1):

This is merely a supplement to the answer. This is how I ended up testing it

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe 'ApiDoc' do
  include ApiDoc

  it "should pass the post to super, ActionDispatch" do
    @path = "path"
    @parameters = {:param1 => "someparam"}
    @headers = {:aheader => "someheaders"}
    ActionDispatch::Integration::Session.any_instance.expects(:post).with(@path, @parameters, @headers)
    post(@path, @parameters, @headers)
  end
end

class DummySuper
  def post(path, parameters=nil, headers=nil)
    #How to verify this is called?
  end
end
class Dummy < DummySuper
  include ApiDoc
end

describe Dummy do

  it "should call super" do
    subject.expects(:enabled?).once.returns(true)
    #how to expect super, the DummySuper.post ?
    path = "path"
    parameters = {:param1 => "someparam"}
    headers = {:aheader => "someheaders"}
    subject.expects(:document_request).with("post", path, parameters, headers)
    subject.post(path, parameters, headers)
  end
end
```

and the slightly modified ApiDoc.

```
module ApiDoc
  def enabled?
    ENV['API_DOC'] == "true"
  end

  def post(path, parameters = nil, headers = nil)
    super
    document_request("post", path, parameters, headers) if enabled?
  end

private
  def document_request(verb, path, parameters, headers)
  ...
  end
end
```

I could verify the super.post in the first test, but I still can't figure out how to do just that with my Dummy class specs.